# React + Flux. Optimised proceedure for passing store state to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, immutable.js

I'm having a little conceptual difficulty with a certain aspect of the React/Flux architecture, I know, crazy, right. It has to do with how a Container should pass the Store to a Component, and how the Component should read from the Store, which as far as I see are interdependent.

As an example - I have a simple chart which updates the x and y range depending on changes to a form. 
I have a simple Store, updated from Dispatch events, "XRANGE_CHANGE" and "YRANGE_CHANGE", of an Action.

```js
import Immutable from "immutable";
import { ReduceStore } from "flux/utils";
import Dispatcher from "../Dispatch";

class ChartStore extends ReduceStore {
    constructor() {
        super(Dispatcher);
    }
    getInitialState() {
        return Immutable.OrderedMap({
            xRange: [],
            yRange: []
        });
    }
    reduce(state, action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case "XRANGE_CHANGE":
                return state.set("xRange", action.item);
            case "YRANGE_CHANGE":
                return state.set("yRange", action.item);
            default:
                console.error("Action type not found");
                return state;
        }
    }
}
export default new ChartStore();
```

And a Container, which will pass this Store to the Chart component;

```js
import React from "react";
import { Container } from "flux/utils";
import ChartAction from "./ChartAction";
import ChartStore from "./ChartStore";
import Chart from "./Component";

class ExampleContainer extends React.Component {
    static calculateState() {
        const chartStore = ChartStore.getState(),
            xRange = chartStore.get("xRange"),
            yRange = chartStore.get("yRange")
        return {
            xRange: xRange,
            yRange: yRange,
            xChange: ChartAction.xChange,
            yChange: ChartAction.yChange
        };
    }
    static getStores() {
        return [ChartStore];
    }
    render() {
        const state = this.state;
        return <Chart
                // actions
                xChange={state.xChange}
                yChange={state.yChange}
                // !!!!! here's where my confusion lies !!!!!
                //store={state.chartStore}
                // ammended
                xRange={state.xRange}
                yRange={state.yRange}
            />
        </div>;
    }
}
export default Container.create(FinanceContainer);
```

The commented exclamation marks above indicate where I lose track of the "accepted" React way of doing things.I'm not quite sure of the best way to pass the Store to the Chart component, which will dictate how I read the Store within the component. I have a few options as far as I see, all work but could be completely wrong.

- As above, I pass the entire store to the Component and in the Components' render function read store.get("xRange") or store.get("yRange")
- In the **Container** I define xRange={chartStore.get("xRange")} etc.
- In **Either** the Container or the Component I perform store.toJSON()/toObject() and read directly from the result.

I could be completely way off the mark with any of these scenarios. Or any of these ways could be fine.

Any advice would be appreciated. As I continue on I'd like to know I'm carrying out a sensible procedure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, this isn't something with a definitive answer.  But I think a good way of determining the "right" methodology is by looking at libraries that are written "for flux" and how they handle these problems.  In particular, I would take a look at Redux (a flux implementation) and Reselect (an extension of Redux that addresses this issue further).

The pattern that these libraries use is essentially that your `calculateState` method ought to transform the flux state into the relevant state information for that container.  It should grab relevant information (e.g. `state.get('xRange')`) as well as possibly performing tranformations on the data held in state if helpful (e.g. `range: {x: state.get('xRange'), y: state.get('yRange')}`).

As with most things in the flux pattern, the idea here is to provide a definitive "source of truth".  You want *every* sub-component to interpret the flux state in the same way, and you want to have a single method to modify, should the data need to be computed differently.  By doing an ETL of the flux state into the container, you achieve that.  Should there be some future change to which piece of the flux state is needed for this section of your app, you would merely need to modify this `calculateState` method, as opposed to all lower usages of that data.

Comment: Thanks. Redux was/is actually my next stop here. It is by far the most referenced external library when navigating through the React learning cycle/minefield. Having to call a getter() to retrieve an item from the Store each time it's needed just seems a little too labour intensive to me.

Comment: You may have misinterpreted my answer then.  If you put the `getter` within the `calculateState` method, then you only need to call such ***once*** and only once.  In contrast, putting the entire flux state into the container state means needing to call the `getter` every time any value is needed in any sub-component.

Comment: I think I see now yes. I've amended the Container code above to calculate any needed state in the calculateState function. Is this what you mean? I'm just mindful here that for a large application, the Container will therefore be doing a lot of work.

Comment: Yep, exactly.  And yes, the container should be doing **all** work related to the flux state.  That's it's job.  It should do nothing else, though.  It's singular responsibility is "talk to flux stores, get data, relay data to more complicated child components".